# Howto connect eclipse RSE to google-compute-engine

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, google-compute-engine

I can't get my Eclipse 3.8 (Ubuntu installation), RSE/TM plugin 3.4 or 3.5 connect with google-compute-engine/debian-7-wheezy-v20140606. I have tried to use vm IP directly and also alias method that **gcloud compute** command line utility provides. Both work from command line but RSE ends up authentication error. It seems that RSE ignores ~/.ssh/config that alias method uses.

Do anyone know what settings/procedure should I use for this connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to make settings.
Supposing that your connection name is **GCE-1**:

1. Open Remote System Explorer perspective.
2. Select **GCE-1** from Remote System Explorer window.
3. Right click -> Properties.
4. Select **Host** at the left panel of "Properties for **GCE-1**" window.
5. Click [Configure proxy settings](http://example.com) at the **Host** panel of "Properties for **GCE-1**" window.
6. Navigate General -> Network Connection -> SSH2.
7. Select General tab.
8. Click <kbd>Add Private Key</kbd> button.
9. Navigate to ~/.ssh.
10. Select **google_compute_engine** and click <kbd>OK</kbd> and <kbd>OK</kbd>.

    Note that GCE command line tools create this file by default.

Done! Now you can navigate e.g. your **Sftp Files** below **GCE-1** Within **Remote Systems window**.